# delete in multi multi delete

Tags: php, mysql

```
DELETE idasignatura, nombre, descripcion 
from asignatura 
WHERE idasignatura IN (SELECT idcat_material 
                       FROM cat_material 
                       WHERE nombre = 'calculo diferencial')
```

este es mi delete cuando la ejecuto me aparece esto

> #1109 - Unknown table 'idasignatura' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: estas tratando de borrar 3 campos de una fila?

Answer (score 2):

Por la SQL que has escrito se puede interpretar dos cosas:

1. Intentas eliminar las filas de la tabla **asignatura** que coincidan con los resultados de la select sobre la tabla **cat_material**. Si es esta la tarea que necesitas hacer, el error está en que no ejecutas correctamente la sentencia [DELETE de MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx/).

   ```
   DELETE FROM asignatura
   WHERE idasignatura IN (SELECT idcat_material 
                          FROM cat_material 
                          WHERE nombre = 'calculo diferencial')
   ```
2. Quieres vaciar los campos **idasignatura**, **nombre**, **descripcion**
   Si es esto lo que quieres hacer, tendrás que actualizar los campos con su valor por defecto. A continuación te indico cómo debería hacerse teniendo en cuenta que los valores por defecto son NULL

   ```
   UPDATE idasignatura SET idasignatura = NULL, 
                           nombre = NULL, 
                           descripcion = NULL,
   WHERE idasignatura IN (SELECT idcat_material 
                          FROM cat_material 
                          WHERE nombre = 'calculo diferencial')`
   ```